# Unable to change font color of the 3rd Slide (Adios Theme)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm not trying to change it globally - just the 3rd Slide.

The Code is -

```
[vc_row fluid="full_stretch_row_content" bg_position="center center" 
class="pb-60 "][vc_column]

[rs_hero_slider speed="400"][rs_hero_slider_item image="484" 
small_heading="Welcome to" 
heading="Guerrilla"]

[rs_hero_slider_item image="493" small_heading="Now's your chance" 
heading="Write, Shoot,
Edit & Repeat"]

[rs_hero_slider_item image="532" small_heading="Preston" heading="City"]
[/rs_hero_slider]

[/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row padding_top="pt-40" padding_bottom="pb-100"]
[vc_column width="1/6" class="col-sm-3"]
[vc_column_text]
```

I've tried adding , [font color] and also CSS but I can't get it to work. The only color option I get is for all 3 slides and I don't want that.

3rd Slide being -

```
[rs_hero_slider_item image="532" small_heading="Preston" heading="City"]
[/rs_hero_slider]
```

Please, can anyone help? Like what I add and where I add it too, if it's CSS could you please provide me with the code? I've tried everything and i can't rattle my brain anymore.

Thanks

Comment: Depending on how the sliders are emulated, e.g. in a `li` or `div`. I would suggest that using a `nth-child(3)` on the slider element from within the CSS you would be able to make apply the CSS to only the third slider. For more information please look at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: If you were able to give the code from the Inspect console of your browser for the entire slider or a link to the slider then I could give you more details to applying this code.